# Subtotals in HTML column2 if column1 matches a criteria

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm trying to create a report, and I need to sum values into a subtotal, based on values in another column.  My problem is, I can't use the SUM command in MySQL, because I'm not dealing with MySQL column names for the table.

I have a set of date ranges, and I need to sum the totals up based on the date range.  I create the date range as a variable, though, so I'm not sure how to sum that up using PHP or MySQL.  (I'm up for using something like jQuery, if it would work.)

The values in the Activity Code column are in the database itself, but the Monitoring Period is taken from the Approval_Date filed from the Plans table of this query:

```
$query = "SELECT * from Plans
Inner JOIN Payroll ON Payroll.Client_ID = Plans.Client_ID";
```

Then this particularly ugly bit of code creates the table:

```
$res = mysqli_query($con, $query);
echo "<div id='payroll'>";
echo "<table class='sortable' style='position:absolute; top: 150px; left: 15px; white-space: nowrap;'>";
echo "<th>Activity Date</th><th>Last Name</th><th>First Name</th><th>PT Last Name</th><th>PT First Name</th><th>Activity Code</th><th class='sorttable_numeric'>Monitoring Period</th><th>Hours</th><th>Rate</th><th>Hourly Pay</th><th>Notes</th>";


while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    foreach($row as $key => $val) {
    $daterange = $row['Approval_Date'];
    $m30 = date('m/d/y',strtotime('+ 30 days', strtotime($daterange)));
    $m60 = date('m/d/y',strtotime('+ 60 days', strtotime($daterange)));
    $m90 = date('m/d/y',strtotime('+ 90 days', strtotime($daterange)));
    $m120 = date('m/d/y',strtotime('+ 120 days', strtotime($daterange)));
    $m150 = date('m/d/y',strtotime('+ 150 days', strtotime($daterange)));
    $m180 = date('m/d/y',strtotime('+ 190 days', strtotime($daterange)));
    $m210 = date('m/d/y',strtotime('+ 210 days', strtotime($daterange)));
    $m240 = date('m/d/y',strtotime('+ 240 days', strtotime($daterange)));
    $m270 = date('m/d/y',strtotime('+ 270 days', strtotime($daterange)));
    $m300 = date('m/d/y',strtotime('+ 300 days', strtotime($daterange)));
    $m330 = date('m/d/y',strtotime('+ 330 days', strtotime($daterange)));
    $m360 = date('m/d/y',strtotime('+ 360 days', strtotime($daterange)));

    $Hourly_Pay = round($row['Pay_Rate'] * $row['Hours'],2);
    asort($row);

        $time = strtotime($val);
        $newformat = date('Y-m-d',$time);
        $myformat = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($row['Date']));

    if ( $time > strtotime("01/01/1969") AND $key == "Date" AND $myformat = $newformat) {
                        echo "<tr><td>" . $row['Date'];  echo "</td><td>" . $row['SC_LName'] . "</td><td>" . $row['SC_FName'] .  "</td><td>" . $row['PT_Last_Name'] . "</td><td>" . $row['PT_First_Name'] . "</td><td>" . $row['Activity_Type'] . "</td><td>"; 
                        if ($row['Activity_Type'] <> "New Plan" AND $row['Activity_Type'] <> "DDD Initial Training" AND $row['Activity_Type'] <> "DSA Initial Training" AND $row['Activity_Type'] <> "CDS Videos") {
                            if (strtotime($row['Date']) <=   strtotime($m30)) {echo date('m/d/y',strtotime('+ 0 days', strtotime($daterange))) . " - " . $m30;}; 
                            if (strtotime($row['Date']) >  strtotime($m30) AND strtotime($row['Date']) < strtotime($m60)) {echo date('m/d/y',strtotime('+ 60 days', strtotime($daterange))) . " - " . $m60 ;}; 
                            if (strtotime($row['Date']) >=  strtotime($m60) AND strtotime($row['Date']) < strtotime($m90)) {echo date('m/d/y',strtotime('+ 60 days', strtotime($daterange))) . " - " . $m90 ;}; 
                            if (strtotime($row['Date']) >= strtotime($m90) AND strtotime($row['Date']) < strtotime($m120)) {echo date('m/d/y',strtotime('+ 90 days', strtotime($daterange))) . " - " . $m120 ;}; 
                            if (strtotime($row['Date']) >= strtotime($m120) AND strtotime($row['Date']) < strtotime($m150)) {echo date('m/d/y',strtotime('+ 120 days', strtotime($daterange))) . " - " . $m150 ;}; 
                            if (strtotime($row['Date']) >= strtotime($m150) AND strtotime($row['Date']) < strtotime($m180)) {echo date('m/d/y',strtotime('+ 150 days', strtotime($daterange))) . " - " . $m180 ;}; 
                            if (strtotime($row['Date']) >= strtotime($m180) AND strtotime($row['Date']) < strtotime($m210)) {echo date('m/d/y',strtotime('+ 180 days', strtotime($daterange))) . " - " . $m210 ;}; 
                            if (strtotime($row['Date']) >= strtotime($m210) AND strtotime($row['Date']) < strtotime($m240)) {echo date('m/d/y',strtotime('+ 210 days', strtotime($daterange))) . " - " . $m240 ;}; 
                            if (strtotime($row['Date']) >= strtotime($m240) AND strtotime($row['Date']) < strtotime($m270)) {echo date('m/d/y',strtotime('+ 240 days', strtotime($daterange))) . " - " . $m270 ;}; 
                            if (strtotime($row['Date']) > strtotime($m270) AND strtotime($row['Date']) < strtotime($m300)) {echo date('m/d/y',strtotime('+ 270 days', strtotime($daterange))) . " - " . $m300;}; 
                            if (strtotime($row['Date']) > strtotime($m300) AND strtotime($row['Date']) < strtotime($m330)) {echo date('m/d/y',strtotime('+ 300 days', strtotime($daterange))) . " - " . $m330;}; 
                            if (strtotime($row['Date']) > strtotime($m330) AND strtotime($row['Date']) < strtotime($m360)) {echo date('m/d/y',strtotime('+ 330 days', strtotime($daterange))) . " - " . $m360 ;}
                            };                              
                            echo "<td>" . $row['Hours'] . "</td><td>" . $row['Pay_Rate'] . "</td><td>" . $Hourly_Pay .  "</td><td>"  . $row['Notes'] . "</td></tr>";
   }
  }
}
echo "</table>";
```

As you may or may not be able to tell from that jumble, it creates a Monitoring Period column with a series of date ranges based on the row's Approval_Date.

My dilemma is that I can't figure out how to get a sum by the Monitoring Period.  Since it's created on the fly, and the column isn't part of the database, I can't get a SUM from MySQL.

Any and all suggestions would be appreciated.  Please let me know if you need additional information.  If there's a jQuery or Javascript way to go about this, I'm fine with that, too. :)

Thanks!

ETA:  It just occurred to me that instead of printing out the data in a table right away, maybe I should take the data and store it in a MySQL table instead.  That way, I could do all the manipulations, and drop the table when I'm done, if I want to. Does that sound possible?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I won't try to read through that jumble of code. What you probably need/can do is: 1. Calculate the subtotal purely in PHP, using the data you already have retrieved earlier from SQL. or 2. Use the new php date variables to create a new SQL query and execute it (attach parameters through PDO).

Comment: Thanks, Dark Ahelin.  I don't think I can use #2 as a solution, because the column isn't in the database.  I'll look into #1.  I'm inclined to try and store the monitoring period in the Plans table, if I can.  That way, at least I can access it as a column.  I'm going to give that a shot and come back if it doesn't work out.

Comment: If you still have trouble or end up stuck somewhere, please try to narrow down your issue and just post the important lines of code. Noone likes to read an entire essay (so to speak).